# How to copy a single sheet from excel having multiple sheets and formulas using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel with with 10 sheets, say sheet1...sheet10 sheets. All of them have formulas too. I copied a single sheet, say sheet2, and made a new excel file using openpyxl.

All the columns that had formulas were replaced with #N/A.

**Code:**

```
workbook = load_workbook('xyz.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook['workbookname']

updatedWorkbook = Workbook()
sheet = updatedWorkbook.active

sheettoCopy = worksheet[f"A1:AB{worksheet.max_row}"]

for i,k in zip(range(1, worksheet.max_row+1), sheettoCopy):
    for j in range(1, worksheet.max_column-1):
        sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value = k[j-1].value

updatedWorkbook.save(filename = 'PFB.xlsx')
```

How do I copy the values? Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code and one of the formulae.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `data only` param to False while loading the spreadsheet to get formulas, from the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae)

```
Help on function load_workbook in module openpyxl.reader.excel:

load_workbook(filename, read_only=False, keep_vba=False, data_only=False, keep_l
inks=True)
    Open the given filename and return the workbook
    
    :param filename: the path to open or a file-like object
    :type filename: string or a file-like object open in binary mode c.f., :clas
s:`zipfile.ZipFile`
    
    :param read_only: optimised for reading, content cannot be edited
    :type read_only: bool
    
    :param keep_vba: preseve vba content (this does NOT mean you can use it)
    :type keep_vba: bool
    
    :param data_only: controls whether cells with formulae have either the formu
la (default) or the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet
    :type data_only: bool
    
    :param keep_links: whether links to external workbooks should be preserved. 
The default is True
    :type keep_links: bool
```

A sample usage :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="sample.xlsx", data_only=False)
```

Let me know how this goes!

Comment: If I set data_only to false, then #REF! shows up.

Comment: Can you share a sample column values  !?

Comment: `data_only=False` is the default.